# Can SEDA help scale a JMS consumer

Tags: apache-camel

If I have a Camel JMS consumer, with

- maxConcurrentConsumers=10
- reading from MQ with max pool size =10 on
  the connection), and
- disableReplyTo=true

**Q1.** Can increasing the maxConcurrentConsumers help scale the route? Once the message is read from the queue, is the connection relinquished?

**Q2.** Can placing a SEDA producer-consumer pattern right after consuming the message help with scaling? Or, is it that one might as well simply increase the maxConcurrentConsumers on the JMS consumer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its generally better to let the scaling be from the JMS consumer, and then scale horizontally by adding more nodes.

The SEDA is an in-memory queue in the JVM and even if you can "scale" by consuming quickly from the JMS queue to the SEDA queue, then you just move the messages from a "safe" storage in the broker to a more "unsafe" store in a JVM in-memory storage.

The JMS broker is built for scaling, and has several architecture styles and topologies for setting up a broker system according to your needs. So its better to leverage it.

The JMS component has options to set concurrency you can tweak as well. And on the JMS client/broker side as well. For example ActiveMQ has prefetch size and others that can be tweaked.

With my commercial hat on: If you are a Fuse subscriber then we have guides for scaling Fuse/AMQ you can also read, and get assistance from our team.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the JMS route is NOT request-reply, and NOT transacted, does each individual "concurrent consumer" try holding on to a connection? Basically, I wondering if my MQ connection pool is (say) a max of 10, can I still get a benefit with 20 concurrent consumers.

Or, is this something that one could control by the CACHE options on the consumer?

Comment: Yeah consumers can scale on top of network connections. The network connections can be pooled and therefore the pooling configuration also matter, and so does networking with TCP/IP settings and all that stuff on the socket/io level. And scaling also depends a bit what you do with the messages in Camel, if they are doing heavy CPU work, or they are mostly doing other IO operations, and waiting for remote services to respond etc.